# Get list item index in HTML ul list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/Menu.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a onclick="GetIndex(this)">One</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="GetIndex(this)">Two</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="GetIndex(this)">Three</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="GetIndex(this)">Four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the Menu.js javascript:

```
function GetIndex(sender)
{   
    var aElements = sender.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var aElementsLength = aElements.length;

    var index;
    for (var i = 0; i < aElementsLength; i++)
    {
        if (aElements[i] == sender) //this condition is never true
        {
            index = i;
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the commented condition never met? How do I compare if the two HTML elements are equal in Javascript? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Not to be mistaken, the main goal here is to get that bloody index. However, learning how to make the disputed condition return true will solve this and many other dilemmas.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me in IE and Chrome, assuming you modify it slightly to do something with `index` inside the condition, instead of just returning it. http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/BcSL7/

Comment: @Andy E: I deleted the `return index;` line and added `alert('Index: ' + index);` to the end of the function and it results in a message "Index: unidentified". :(

Comment: wow it works now! what the hell... could it be that my page or javascript was cached?

Comment: whoever wants to write "Your code is correct" in the answer will get points for providing the right answer :)

Comment: fully related, perhaps duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026485/how-to-iterate-through-ul-list-using-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "Your code is correct"

Answer (score 2):

Old Post, but here is a quick function to do this:

```
function nodeIndex(el) {
    var i=0;
    while(el.previousElementSibling ) {
        el=el.previousElementSibling;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This should work with an element reference as the parameter. It basically just returns the number of previous siblings.

Answer (score 1):

try to use:

if (aElements[i] === sender)

instead of

```
if (aElements[i] == sender)
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to find index of element

```
[...el.parentNode.children].indexOf(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure GetIndex function gets executed on click event on anchor tag?

Try by giving href attribute to anchor tag. You can write either

```
<a href="#" onclick="GetIndex(this)">One</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GetIndex(this)">One</a>
```

here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/QfRSb/

Comment: I am quite sure, because in my 'real' example, the backgrounds of the `<a>` elements are changing in the loop. That proves that the function does get executed. (BWT, I am using Chrome. I don't know if it matters...)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can help using `prevAll()`

```
$(document).on("click","li",function(){
 var index=$(this).prevAll();
 alert(index);
});
```