# Need to add Prev/Next toggles to tab script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Here is the JS Fiddle of my existing tab build:

http://jsfiddle.net/getpresto/89ZAG/1/

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need is the ability to add a far left button that will cycle the user to the next tab to the left and a far right button that will cycle the user to the right tab.  If the user reaches either end and continues to click the same prev or next option then they will simply continue through to the other end of tabs.  So if they are on tab 1 and click the left navigation button then they will go to tab 3 as an example.

How can I adjust this script to include this feature?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: you could di this with jquery http://rmurphey.com/blog/2008/01/08/cycle-through-list-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I am reviewing this now.

Comment: or check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026485/how-to-iterate-through-ul-list-using-javascript

Comment: Are you really using jQuery 1.7 as per your JSFiddle? That changes things if you are.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I am running 1.7.2, but I can easily increase it if needed.  Can you make a recommendation on the version and changes?

Comment: I would recommend. 1.10 or above. Running latest jQuery 1.11.1 myself. The methods on `tabs` get better after 1.9's matching UI version.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie well... the CMS currently maxes out at 1.9.1...

Comment: go with 1.9.1. That has the final `tabs` additions (just trying to get your example to work at all with 1.9.1) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I just updated the fiddle, but this knocked out the tab function.

Comment: Which is what I found too, even using the matching JQ-UI version. It expects a different structure!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55511/discussion-between-presto-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic steps for any version will be:

- You need to get the current selected tab index,
- alter it with `+1` or `-1` (depending on the button pressed),
- then wrap the value based on the number of tabs,
- then update the current tab.

If you can upgrade to JS 1.9.1 or higher something like this will work:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89ZAG/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectTab = function (delta) {
        //var index = $("#tabs .current").parent().index();
        var index = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
        var count = $("#tabs ul > li").length;
        index += delta;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = count - 1;
        }
        if (index >= count) {
            index = 0;
        }
        $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', index);
    };

    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        selectTab(-1);
    });
    $('#next').click(function () {
        selectTab(1);
    });
}); //end document ready
```

But the HTML also needs to be restructured to suit that later `tabs` requirements (the panel selectors are in the link `href` properties:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs header">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panes" id="tab1">
        <!--Start Tab 1-->Tab 1 content.</div>
    <div class="panes" id="tab2">
        <!--End Tab 1 & Start Tab 2-->Tab 2 content.</div>
    <div class="panes" id="tab3">
        <!--End Tab 2 & Start Tab 3-->Tab 3 content.</div>
    <!--End Tab 3-->
    <!--End Panes-->
</div>
<input class="header" type="button" value="Prev" id="prev" />
<input class="header" type="button" value="Next" id="next" />
```

*You will need to style the two buttons so they appear beside/over your tabs.*